# Labels not printing issues in Win 7

Tags: windows, vb.net, 64-bit

First of all, we have an application developed in .Net and used on a Win XP platform for years with very little problems.

We recently switched to Win 7 64bit and we are having issues with labels not printing.

When the user selects a job it may have several products it needs to print per order line.
What is happening, is sometimes labels aren't being printed for an specific order line.

For instance, let's say we have job X with 8 order lines to print.
The application sends the labels to a preview window using crystal reports and then immediately sends it to the printer without any human intervention.

- line 4 with quantity 1, doesn't print
- line 5 with quantity 1, doesn't print
- line 6 with quantity 1, doesn't print
- line 7 with quantity 3, doesn't print
- line 1 with quantity 1, doesn't print
- line 2 with quantity 2, prints
- line 3 with quantity 28, prints
- line 8 with quantity 1, doesn't print
  If this same job is printed on a Win XP PC it doesn't have any problems and all the lines and appropriate quantities are printed.

We are using Zebra setup utilities 1.1.9.1060.
we have a

- ZM400 with firmware v53.17.11Z
- ZM400 with firmware v53.17.9Z
- ZM400 with firmware v53.17.5Z
- ZM4Plus with firmware v60.14.3Z

These printers are connected to the PC over the network via a TCPIP address.

Also, we are using Windows driver Z4M 203DPI printer version 2.6.77 (Build 3827)

Let me know any other information you may need.
Thank you,
Tim Caldwell.

Comment: I'll bet the printer driver is just incompatible with Win7-64. That happened a lot in the XP->Vista transition. Does the printer work with applications other than yours?

Comment: Michael - the printer is only used by this one application.
The printers are purpose built label printers using heat transfer.

We've narrowed the problem down and it appears to be something with either the driver in Win7 or Win7 itself.
The labels not coming out or with an incorrect quantity appears to only happen when we send a label with a copy count that exceeds 2.
We've gotten around the issue by sending each print to the printer with only a copy count of 1 and pausing for 1/2 a second.
We've had zero issues since making this change.

Comment: Michael - The printer driver is certified Win 7 compatible and yes it does work other applications.  I currently have a ticket open with Zebra, but I'm not expecting anything to come out of it.